# Perfect forwarding and std::move behavior within this context

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I am a C++ newbie and I want to understand how the perfect forwarding works in conjunction with `std::move`.

I define a `std::vector<QueueData> queue()` that I want to populate using the template function `fillWithData`. Since I spent some time to study perfect forwarding I want, first, to check if I understood correctly and secondly to figure out what's the `move` behaviour withing this context.

`fillWithData` is a variadic template function that, thanks to `forward`, is able to treat the parameters as lvalue or rvalue through the collapsing rules. (**Q1** - is it correct?)

```
template< class Container, typename ... Args >
static void fillWithData(Container & oDataContainer, 
                         Args&& ... args)  // universal reference
{
    typedef typename Container::value_type::element_type QueueDataPtr;
    oDataContainer.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Now, imagine there is an object `User usr` from which to take the arguments to pass to `fillWithData`:

if I call `fillWithData( queue, usr.getName(), usr.getEmail(), usr.getAddr() )` will the `emplace` do the following calls?

- Constructor for a temporary QueueData object;
- Move constructor (if one was defined for the temporary, otherwise a copy constructor) for the object actually allocated inside the vector;
- Destructor for the temporary;

If I want to optimize I could take advantage of the `move` that will treat the lvalue as rvalue (**Q2** - is `usr.getName()` a lvalue?):

`fillWithData( queue, 
               std::move(usr.getName()), 
               std::move(usr.getEmail()),
               std::move(usr.getAddr()) )`

In this way, (**Q3**) are the values forwarded directly to `User` constructor and is the new object directly constructed inside the vector?

Moreover (**Q4**) if, for example, I do a new call to `usr.getName()` just after the call to `fillWithData`, will the data be still available? (I guess I'll have runtime errors).

Finally (**Q5**), without the `std::move`, does it make sense to implement the perfect forwarding?

Thanks.

Comment: One question per question, please. Not five.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::move` does not perform perfect forwarding. It casts an l-value reference into an r-value reference. Since it has performed a cast, the input is different to the output - so not perfect.

`std::forward<X>` performs perfect forwarding, but it requires that the type of X is being deduced (i.e. it's a template argument of the current function and it's a universal reference).

One might ask why `std::move` must be called on a seemingly r-value reference variable name.

This is **because any variable with a name is actually an l-value**, regardless of whether it's declared with one `&` or two.

so...

`int&& x = y();` is an l-value which will only bind to an r-value (y must return an r-value reference or a temporary).

`int& x = y();` is also an l-value, but it will bind to either an l-value or an r-value (y may return either an int&, or an int&&).

In the above cases, `std::move(x)` returns an r-value reference. In the first case it would be (seemingly) perfect, in the second it would have been cast - therefore not perfectly forwarded.

`std::forward<>` detects the difference whereas `std::move` does not.

In summary, *in a deduced context*, `std::forward<T>(x)` will return the exact same category (l-valuenes or r-valueness) of x as was passed in the function's argument, whereas `std::move` will always return an r-value reference, even if passed an l-value reference.

confused? There's a simple rule of thumb:

Given:

```
template<class T> void bar(T x);   // pass by value
```

Then:

```
template<class Deduced> void foo(Deduced&& x)
{
    // x is a universal reference in deduced context, 
    // so we probably want to forward it.
    bar(std::forward<Deduced>(x));
}

void foo(Known&& x)
{
    // x is definitely an r-value reference. No point forwarding something
    // we already know the category of - move it.
    bar(std::move(x));
}

void foo(Known x)
{
    // x is definitely an l-value. No point forwarding an l-value
    // reference, as this will cause an un-necessary copy. 
    // So we must cast x.
    bar(std::move(x));
}

void foo(Known const& x)
{
    // x is definitely a const l-value reference. No point forwarding 
    // a const reference, and no point moving it, since a 
    // (Known const &&) is not useful.
    // Whatever we do, there's going to be a copy.
    bar(x);
}
```

Comment: Actually in your "void foo(Known x)" example the correct thing to do is to just pass x as-is to bar(): guaranteed copy elision means that no extra copy will be made that wouldn't have been made in the first place. Actually doing bar(std::move(x)) there doesn't achieve anything, it's strictly equivalent to bar(x) - I'd expect the same assembly to be generated.